# What was my wife trying to say?

Tags: visual, cipher

One day, my Japanese wife Nono handed me two messages

> 580D10F20G10D13011173203443206640942092330411622053222041112103112221032212210421142012234130580236905325A031112H042127905121890142726016135802622212602A22270B412230846250A731106526107324208322081122056

and

> 7109501A350726505138504112A0423A0222290331A02225302142213043112220143341203421211204141211210524122206122112106133123072351211071912120629222072B4206122714205236112105313222104222223106162210121262220121281320335B204A40A10D0D0E

"I have something to tell you. Decrypt my message and you'll see", she said while smiling at me.

It took me a while but when I finally got a result I was full of joy! Why was I happy?

**Hint 1**

> You can solve this using only pen and paper

**Hint 2**

> My wife's name is an important clue

**Hint 3**

> One of the characters acts as a separator

Comment: first thought was to use the zeros to separate the rest and convert Hex to binary or something, but then I realized there are H's and G's in there :P   maybe this will give someone a clue on how to approach this. GL

Comment: I think this is a nonogram where 0 are the separators of the columns. There are 35 zeros in each string.

Comment: @Element118 ouch, that would be a mistake from me because you're on the right track and they should be equal on that mapping. I'm going to find the error and fix it in a couple of minutes

Answer (score 73, accepted):

This is

> a nonogram where the zeroes are the separators of the columns. The letters map to numbers above 10: A$\rightarrow$10, B$\rightarrow$11 and so on. Using an [online solver](http://www.lancs.ac.uk/~simpsons/nonogram/auto) and the following text input, I received an image.

Text input:

> ```
>     width 35
>     height 35
>  
>     rows
>     5,8
>     13,1
>     15,2
>     16,1
>     13,1,3
>     1,1,1,7,3,2
>     3,4,4,3,2
>     6,6,4
>     9,4,2
>     9,2,3,3
>     4,1,1,6,2,2
>     5,3,2,2,2
>     4,1,1,1,2,1
>     3,1,1,2,2,2,1
>     3,2,2,1,2,2,1
>     4,2,1,1,4,2
>     1,2,2,3,4,1,3
>     5,8
>     2,3,6,9
>     5,3,2,5,10
>     3,1,1,1,2,17
>     4,2,1,2,7,9
>     5,1,2,1,8,9
>     1,4,2,7,2,6
>     1,6,1,3,5,8
>     2,6,2,2,2,1,2,6
>     2,10,2,2,2,7
>     11,4,1,2,2,3
>     8,4,6,2,5
>     10,7,3,1,1
>     6,5,2,6,1
>     7,3,2,4,2
>     8,3,2,2
>     8,1,1,2,2
>     5,6
>
>
>     columns
>     7,1
>     9,5
>     1,10,3,5
>     7,2,6,5
>     5,1,3,8,5
>     4,1,1,2,10
>     4,2,3,10
>     2,2,2,2,9
>     3,3,1,10
>     2,2,2,5,3
>     2,1,4,2,2,1,3
>     4,3,1,1,2,2,2
>     1,4,3,3,4,1,2
>     3,4,2,1,2,1,1,2
>     4,1,4,1,2,1,1,2,1
>     5,2,4,1,2,2,2
>     6,1,2,2,1,1,2,1
>     6,1,3,3,1,2,3
>     7,2,3,5,1,2,1,1
>     7,1,9,1,2,1,2
>     6,2,9,2,2,2
>     7,2,11,4,2
>     6,1,2,2,7,1,4,2
>     5,2,3,6,1,1,2,1
>     5,3,1,3,2,2,2,1
>     4,2,2,2,2,2,3,1
>     6,1,6,2,2,1
>     1,2,1,2,6,2,2,2
>     1,2,1,2,8,1,3,2
>     3,3,5,11,2
>     4,10,4
>     10,1
>     13
>     13
>     14
> ```

output:

> [image]

It took me a while but when I finally got a result I was full of joy! Why was I happy?

> You have a new member in your family! Congratulations!

Comment: Great job! I added a nicer output if you don't mind :)

Comment: Who needs a sonogram when a nonogram will do.

Comment: Congrats! But to be honest, I guessed it as soon as I saw "I have something to tell you" and "...smiling at me".

Comment: Forget the answer tell me how you made that image! :)

Comment: @HankyPanky the nonogram itself I didn't create myself. I used Google image search for "nonogram baby" and ended up with that one. The rest of the puzzle I did came up by myself.